# Triggering column after update issue

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I got a problem with a trigger I'm trying to implement into my program.

I got a table called Products it has columns as ID, PRICE and DISCOUNT

I made this trigger:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER DISCOUNT_TRIGGER
    after update of DISCOUNT on PRODUCTS
    for each row
    BEGIN
            update PRODUCTS set PRICE = PRICE * (1 - DISCOUNT);
    END;
```

I want to change the price column of the row after an update of discount column.

For example if I execute this query:

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS SET DISCOUNT = 25 WHERE ID = 25;
```

When I execute that query I'm getting the following error:

```
Error starting at line : 11 in command -
update products set DISCOUNT = 25 where id = 1
Error report -
ORA-04091: table YASSINEII.PRODUCTS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "YASSINEII.DISCOUNT_TRIGGER", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'YASSINEII.DISCOUNT_TRIGGER'
```

Any idea what im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you really want a "before update" trigger that updates values in a single row.  Something like:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER DISCOUNT_TRIGGER
    before update of DISCOUNT on PRODUCTS
    for each row
BEGIN
    :new.price := :new.price * ( 1 - :new.korting_percentage);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your fast answer, i tried that but it gives me this error:

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
2/5       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
2/41      PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.KORTING_PERCENTAGE' must be declared
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: @J.Adam: you replaced `korting_percentage` with `discount` in your question after Gordon answered. If you don't have a column `korting_percentage` then apparently you need to use the column you have `:new.discount`

Answer (score 0):

You can't query the table that caused a trigger to fire inside the trigger itself.

But in this case, I don't see any need to. You can use :new to access the values you're selecting from the table

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER DISCOUNT_TRIGGER
    after update of DISCOUNT on PRODUCTS
    for each row
    BEGIN
            update PRODUCTS set :new.PRICE = :new.PRICE * (1 - korting_percentage);
    END;
```

Comment: That will result in the same error as you are using an UPDATE statement on the table that caused the trigger to fire.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid mutating table exception using compound triggers.

Here the example (remember to change the table and the columns by which they fit your data model):

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER DISCOUNT_TRIGGER
    FOR UPDATE of DISCOUNT on PRODUCTS
    COMPOUND TRIGGER

    BEFORE STATEMENT is
    BEGIN
            UPDATE your_table SET your_column = your_value WHERE your_condition;
    END BEFORE STATEMENT;

    --BEFORE EACH ROW is
    --BEGIN
            --Put here the statement
    --END BEFORE EACH ROW;

    --AFTER STATEMENT is
    --BEGIN
            --Put here the statement
    --END AFTER STATEMENT;

    --AFTER EACH ROW is
    --BEGIN
            --Put here the statement
    --END AFTER EACH ROW;

END;
```